# Reliable source regarding life just after Aegon's conquest

Tags: lore, song-of-ice-and-fire-rpg

I am planning to run my game of thrones game right after Aegon has conquered Westeros. Are there any lore guides regarding the situation during that time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs either in literature.stackexchange.com or scifi.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You have a little info about the politics in the Song of Ice and Fire rpg campaign guide (about a page or so) and a lot about the geography, and most likely there's more to find. I don't turn this into an answer, however, because I'm flagging this question as off-topic for asking for recoomendations, sorry.

Comment: This question blurs the lines between scifi and rpg stacks. Im voting it as offtopic here because that cannot be answered by any of the rpg books (afaik). But it can be answered partially by one of the lore books unrelated to the rpg.

Comment: I'd recommend asking about the lore on [SciFi stack exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/); I  have found that there is a wealth of knowledge there on this very topic.  You can adapt that to your campaign as you need it. |